# Given a matrix A, return a vector v in a way that depends on the injective, surjective, and bijective properties of A

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix A which is a bijective matrix

```
A= np.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[4,10,6]])
```

Return a vector v where the first two coordinate of v are 1 and v=Ax for some vector x.
[image]

This is how I calculate vector v, but I got the wrong answer.

```
import numpy as np    
one_array = np.array([1,2,1])
one_array.shape=(3,1)
A_inv = np.linalg.inv(A)
v = np.dot(A_inv, np.dot(A, one_array))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# A is injective
v = np.array([1,1,-4])
```